# UWP Access Denied to StorageFile

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I'm getting access denied when using

```
StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath)
```

From other posts and some documentation that I read UWP can only access to video lib, videos, (profile related folders) when declared in the `Package.appxmanifest` etc...

With FilePicker I have no problem accessing these locations, but the `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` was to automatically load those files into a list when the page loads.

How can I use this function to load files outside known folders video lib, videos, etc.

Comment: I think the procedure is to ask the user for permission on the _folder_ and then you can  store that for future use.

Comment: How can I do that using StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync?

Comment: This is the dupest of duplicates, Please look up **broadFileSystemAccess** over at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use this method to access files on those safe paths UWP apps have access to. If you get access to another location via a file or folder picker, you must cache access to it using `Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList`. This API allows you to store an existing instance of `StorageFile` or `StorageFolder` and gives you a "token", which is a `string` by which you can later access the selected `StorageItem` again.

```
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    string faToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);  
}
```

Now that the file is in `FutureAccessList`, you can later retrieve it:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(faToken);
```

Items stored in `FutureAccessList` survive even when the app is closed and reopened so it is probably the ideal solution for your use case. However, keep in mind the `FutureAccessList` can store at most 1000 items (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist)), and you must maintain it - so if you no longer need an item, make sure you delete it, so that it does not count towards the limit anymore.

The second solution would be to declare the [`broadFileSystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). This is however a restricted capability and your app must have a good reason to use it.

Comment: Hi, I tried the broadFileSystemAccess but no success. The goal is to save those FS locations then App will monitor those folder paths and process the files in it (is a file watcher), that said, you say the FutureAccessList will survive when the app closes, but will it survive at computer reboots? You see I don't want to have to configure those FS locations each time I reboot the computer. The way that I though about this was to configure these locations 1 time in file settings then an auto process will monitor those locations each time the app runs

Comment: Yes, FutureAccessList will survive both app close and computer reboots. As long as you have the token, you will be able to retrieve the reference from FAL any time.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it worked and please consider marking the question as solved :-) .

Comment: The solution works, but for my scenario I need to think how to implement this since there are other things to consider :)